# Magento on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, mysql, magento, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm thinking to move the content of my VPS on an Amazon EC2 instance.

I'm trying to understand what "pieces" do I need to make my Amazon RI persistent, it would run 100% time, and I'd like to avoid data loss (such as if I reboot/stop the machine).
I've read this on a blog, but I think it would refer to the machine termination (not stop).

By the way here are some questions I'd like to ask you:

- Do I need to purchase an EBS volume to have some storage or it's also
  shipped with the Instance itself?
- If I've an instance storage what is the benefit of EBS over it?
- What kind of storage would you suggest to have persistent storage? (nobody will access via APIs so there's no chance someone will ever touch the data except the application itself).
- Do you think a Small Instance would be good to
  serve a MagentoCommerce with hundreds of products?
- Is the year renewal automatical? Will it require to pay again the one-time fee (for a RI)?
- Do you have any experience or suggestion to take care while choosing which Instance type should I buy?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking such specific questions to Amazon instead of here?

Comment: this iss off-topic here and no small instance does not suite EC2 has terrible IO performance so expect Magento to crawl

Comment: @AntonS Why is this off topic? it's a specific question on amazon services...

Comment: @ErwinMoller I was just asking here to hear from someone that maybe did something similiar and could share some knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

- You can use an EBS backed instance where the EBS volume is the core volume.  You can add additional EBS volumes for more disk space
- The only real benefit of instance storage over EBS in my opinion is the cost savings, the persistence of EBS is a major plus.
- Despite the comment above, I've set up Magento stores using multiple EBS volumes arranged in a RAID0 and achieved decent I/O.  Be prepared to tune and tweak the server.
- Instance size is going to be dependent on traffic and load.  Without knowing either, my guess is that a small isn't going to perform well.  I've seen a c1-xlarge hosting both Magento and the DB perform well with 15,000 uniques a day.
- The 64 bit instances have more options for up sizing and downsizing.

Moving on to AWS involves trade-offs.  You're going to get better hardware performance from a dedicated physical box, but you'll loose flexibility.  Depending on how your payment gateway is setup, you may have PCI compliance issues in the cloud.

Comment: reading http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ it seems that I already buy an Instance Storage, am I wrong? And why there's an "EBS-Optimized Available: No"? Can you help me to understand this?